# Power Automate - Sharepoint List "when an Item is created"

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

All,

I am trying to add in a Flow - I have a list within one of the sites, Where i would like to receive Notifications of any New Item added to the List or if there are any modifications done

"I use the Trigger called as **when an Item is Created** and select the Appropriate Site where the list is located" - But for some reason i am not able to populate the List Name in there.

"Where as if i use Trigger called When a file is created (Properties Only)" That does show me the list name in there and the folder name as well. "But i want to Trigger when an Item is added to a list" Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be easier to use an alert for this, then it would not count against your monthly flow runs.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually happens for no reason, I used to have the same issue as yours. You could click "Enter custom value", and enter your list name manually. This works for me.

Comment: That looks to be working for me but for some reason the workflow did run correctly 3-4 Times after which i get this    "ResponseSwaggerSchemaValidationFailure. The API 'sharepointonline' returned an invalid response for workflow operation 'When_an_item_is_created' of type 'OpenApiConnection'. Error details: 'The API operation 'GetOnNewItems' is missing required property 'body/value/0/Ops_x0020_Request_x0020_ID'.'"